# When do you need a complex termination?

Tags: termination

The formula for the characteristic impedance is below
[image]

So the characteristic impedance is a complex number. But why is a complex termination generally not used?

With complex termination I mean a transmission line terminated by more than just a resistor. Maybe a resistor and a capacitor.

Comment: A less complex designation could be non-resistive termination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *So the characteristic impedance is a complex number. But why is never
> a complex termination used?*

When \$j\omega\$ is significant, the formula reduces to this: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{j\omega L}{j\omega C}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}} = \text{resistance}$$

This applies pretty much to frequencies of 1 MHz and greater i.e. the vast majority of RF applications.

At audio frequencies, the equation becomes more complex and is usually approximated to this: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{R}{j\omega C}}$$

So, for telephony applications, a complex termination method is used (in order to reduce telephone side-tone) like this: -

[image]

New Zealand and the UK use the above complex impedance for terminating a telephone cable in order to optimize the anti-side-tone circuit. Other countries use similar but not identical values.

Generally, a cable will exhibit this type of impedance response: -

[image]

At DC (well, 30 Hz) the impedance is determined by the ratio \$\sqrt{\frac{R}{G}}\$ and if R = 1 Ω then, according to the above (taken from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_impedance)), \$\frac{1}{G}\$ has to be 1.6 GΩ and this wouldn't surprise anyone I would think! But, it all gets a little messy at mid-band audio and up to about 100 kHz for most cables.

Comment: Thanks again. You wanted to add a picture that might help for the microcap installation. Could you please notify me if you do?

Comment: @Yoomo I added it to the bottom of my previous answer on TDR. It wasn't for installation; it was for how to set up a transmission line. I can't help with the install.

Answer (score 5):

When designing an transmission line, we typically want to make \$R\$ and \$G\$ as small as possible such that they are negligible.

If \$\omega L\$ and \$\omega C\$ are much larger than \$R\$ and \$G\$, then things simplify:

$$Z_0 \approx \sqrt{\frac{j\omega L}{j\omega C}} = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$$

The characteristic impedance becomes entirely real as a result, meaning the termination can then be acheived with a simple resistor.

---

Bear in mind this is just an approximation. It is not possible to completely zero \$R\$ and \$G\$, making all real transmissions lines have a small imaginary component. However this imaginary component is usually small enough that practical circuits will still function without a perfect match.

For very high frequencies or very low frequencies, we tend to include matching components such as transmission line stubs or series and parallel reactive components to transform the imaginary component to a real component over a limited frequency range of interest.

Comment: So there is no such thing as a complex transmission line?

Comment: @Yoomo One with significant R or G would have complex impedance, so it can exist.